# what are requirements for collecting Deblur_Net?

Tags: deep-learning

Collecting Deblur_Net

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
>   Deblur_Net (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found
>   for Deblur_Net

I have tried installing latest version of tensorflow on google colab

```
import tensorflow as tf
from Deblur_Net import Deblur_Net
from mode import *
import argparse
```

Deblur_Net should be installed.